# SSD suddenly becomes unreadable - how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, smart, manjaro

I got a new laptop a few days ago, a Thinkpad x270. Unfortunately, I have had a few instances where it sort of crashed.I believe that it's something to do with the built-in SSD, but I can't diagnose it properly.

I'm running a fresh install of Manjaro 17.

When the "crash" occurs, some applications crash, others manage to stick around but none of them are able to function properly. Almost anything I try to do fails with an I/O error. On the desktop, all the icons are wrong. Clicking on the power menu shows the menu, but none of the text or icons are loaded. If I switch to another tty I see a few messages about `ext4-fs error unable to read itable block` but never get to log in.

I'm pretty sure that this means it's due to my SSD, but forcing fsck at boot didn't seem to do anything and gsmartcontrol says that the drive doesn't support SMART.

**How do I diagnose my problem properly, so I can fix it or get my laptop exchanged?**

Here's the output of gsmartcontrol, if it helps:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.9.16-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       THNSF5512GPUK TOSHIBA
Serial Number:                      17IS10D1TANT
Firmware Version:                   51025KLA
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1179
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x00080d
Controller ID:                      0
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512'110'190'592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Sat Apr  1 07:44:55 2017 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL *Other*
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     78 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     3.90W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.1200W       -        -    3  3  3  3     1000    1000
 4 -   0.0120W       -        -    4  4  4  4     5000   10000
 5 -   0.0060W       -        -    5  5  5  5   100000   50000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
Read NVMe SMART/Health Information failed: NVMe Status 0x4002
```

Edited to add:
Since then, I booted into sysrescuecd and used badblocks and fsck to try and find any errors with the drive, but both tests came back without errors.

That leaves me even more confused. What could possibly cause the errors I'm seeing, yet not be visible to the diagnostics?

Update again: 
I sent the laptop in, got the SSD exchanged, no problem - but the error came back. So since it's not the SSD (as badblocks suggested) what else can it be? Software after all?

Comment: Well, luckily I can still boot the computer fine and access all the contents, plus of course it's freshly set up, so the only data on there is stuff I had backed up and *just* put there. I'll return it through warranty and get a new one. But I'd like to be sure that it's actually the hardware that's broken, and right now I feel that I can't be sure.

This was a response to a comment telling me to take it to a Data Recovery specialist.

Comment: We cannot do a technician's job through remote control. If it's a brand new computer and it crashes, just replace it. If the replacement crashes, ask for reimbursement. Easy.

Comment: I'd like to be able to diagnose the problem, even so. After all, sending it in is a hassle and takes time.

Comment: You can only search for logged error messages (see [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/143642/is-there-something-like-windows-event-viewer-in-linux-platform)) and run stress tests. Your problem will be, as you have installed the OS yourself, to convince the vendor that it's his problem.

Comment: A possible issue with the motherboard, for example? I think if this happens  even with a replaced SSD, that's definitely not an SSD problem. Any chance of whole laptop RMA?

Comment: So, after getting the SSD replaced, ensuring that wasn't the fault, I looked for more diagnosing tools, which led me to find a patched Linux kernel which ostensibly deals with quirks that some NVMe SSDs have. Found [here](https://github.com/damige/linux-nvme).

Reading into why this kernel exists, led me to believe that it isn't purely hardware, but in fact a Linux kernel problem! Apparently some SSDs behave oddly and Linux can't gracefully handle that yet.

Comment: Additionally, I found a thread on the Lenovo support forums, which suggested that a BIOS update might help. There is apparently a known issue with the x270's SSD not waking up from low-power states.

So now I'm trying the new kernel. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, after futilely trying more diagnostics[1] and a patched Linux kernel, the correct solution seems to have been a BIOS update.

Apparently, under older versions of the BIOS of my Lenovo x270, there are issues with the SSD not powering up again after going to a low-power state.

Applying the BIOS update was not entirely trivial, as I do not run Windows on my laptop, so the [utility](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ch/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x270/downloads/ds105890) was not helpful and the bootable image from the same page is in a weird Lenovo-specific format and none of my usual tools were able to create a bootable USB stick from that. However, that too is a known issue and someone created a [Perl script](https://github.com/ksergey/thinkpad/blob/master/geteltorito.pl) to extract the actual ISO file from the Lenovo-provided file. Using this script's `-o` option, I created an ISO file that I was able to boot from and apply the update.

Since then, my laptop seems to run stable.

[1]: The `nvme-cli` tool was useful for getting more info on my SSD, though, and it ultimately, if coincidentally, lead me to the solution.

Comment: +1 for posting your own solution in detail so it can help others in the future who come here with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you and that's exactly why I posted it. Too often have I run into a situation like in this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/) myself^^ So I try to always have an answer in any thread I create.

Comment: +1 for including an applicable xkcd reference